# Async / Await cause a loop

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, async-await

I try to use the Async / Await instead of .then() with a promise.
With the .then() Method my code works fine...

### When i change it to Async / Await then i got a loop

Antother Question: How can i disable the Promise  in my console.log()?

Thank you .........

```
ASCBY1
state:2
ASCBY1
state:2
ASCBY1
Promise { <pending> }
state:2
ASCBY1
state:2
ASCBY1
state:2
ASCBY1
state:2
ASCBY1
state:2
ASCBY1
state:2
ASCBY1
Promise { <pending> }
state:2
ASCBY1
state:2
ASCBY1
state:2
ASCBY1
state:2
ASCBY1
Promise { <pending> }
state:2
ASCBY1
state:2
ASCBY1
Promise { <pending> }
state:2
ASCBY1
state:2
ASCBY1
state:2
```

**This is working fine **

```js
  
  
  private innerLoop(i,ifArray,counter,cb){
    let tempMod = new Module(null, ifArray[i].id,ifArray[i].type);
    /*FALLS CHCEK BY MODULE*/

    if(ifArray[i].timerID === 0){ //WENN ein Timer ausgeführt iwrd, dann gibt es kein Modul bzw. kein DevType, er muss aber dennoch durch alle Schleifen (ifArray) laufen. Ohne der && this.mod.... würde er bei switch case ein Fehler ausspucken weil es den DevType nicht gibt.
      if(!(this.mod === undefined)){
      //  var tempMod = new Module(ifArray[i].id,ifArray[i].type);
        setTimeout(()=>console.log(tempMod.getState()),1000);
        switch (this.mod.modulesRecievedData.DevType){
           case 0x0b:{
             if(this.mod.checkMultiSwitch(ifArray[i])){
               counter++;
             }
             break;
           }
           case 0x02:{
              console.log("ASCBY1");

              tempMod.getState().then((state)=>{
                if(state == 2) counter++;

                console.log("state:"+state);

                if(i < ifArray.length){//NUR WENN TIMERID == 0 ist, sonst zählt er den Timer mit obwohl da keine ID + type dahinter steckt.
                  this.innerLoop(i,ifArray,counter,cb);
                }else{
                  cb(counter);
                }
              });


              break;
           }
        }
        i++;
      }
    }else if(ifArray[i].timerID > 0){  /*FALLS CHECK BY TIMER*/
      var timerOnState = time[ifArray[i].timerID].timerOnState;
      if(timerOnState == true){
        counter++;
      }
      i++;
      if(i < ifArray.length){//NUR WENN TIMERID == 0 ist, sonst zählt er den Timer mit obwohl da keine ID + type dahinter steckt.
        this.innerLoop(i,ifArray,counter,cb);
      }else{
         console.log("counter3 "+counter);
        cb(counter);
      }
    }
  }
```

**This cause a look**

```js
private async innerLoop(i,ifArray,counter,cb){
    let tempMod = new Module(null, ifArray[i].id,ifArray[i].type);
    /*FALLS CHCEK BY MODULE*/

    if(ifArray[i].timerID === 0){ //WENN ein Timer ausgeführt iwrd, dann gibt es kein Modul bzw. kein DevType, er muss aber dennoch durch alle Schleifen (ifArray) laufen. Ohne der && this.mod.... würde er bei switch case ein Fehler ausspucken weil es den DevType nicht gibt.
      if(!(this.mod === undefined)){
      //  var tempMod = new Module(ifArray[i].id,ifArray[i].type);
        setTimeout(()=>console.log(tempMod.getState()),1000);
        switch (this.mod.modulesRecievedData.DevType){
           case 0x0b:{
             if(this.mod.checkMultiSwitch(ifArray[i])){
               counter++;
             }
             break;
           }
           case 0x02:{
              console.log("ASCBY1");
              ///////////////////////////////////
              //////HERE IS THE CHANGE///////////
              ///////////////////////////////////
              let state = await tempMod.getState();

              if(state == 2) counter++;

              console.log("state:"+state);

              if(i < ifArray.length){//NUR WENN TIMERID == 0 ist, sonst zählt er den Timer mit obwohl da keine ID + type dahinter steckt.
                this.innerLoop(i,ifArray,counter,cb);
              }else{
                cb(counter);
              }
              break;
           }
        }
        i++;
      }
    }else if(ifArray[i].timerID > 0){  /*FALLS CHECK BY TIMER*/
      var timerOnState = time[ifArray[i].timerID].timerOnState;
      if(timerOnState == true){
        counter++;
      }
      i++;
      if(i < ifArray.length){//NUR WENN TIMERID == 0 ist, sonst zählt er den Timer mit obwohl da keine ID + type dahinter steckt.
        this.innerLoop(i,ifArray,counter,cb);
      }else{
         console.log("counter3 "+counter);
        cb(counter);
      }
    }
  }
```

*Module class*

```js
 getState(){
  let promise = new Promise((resolve)=>{
   this.db.getStateOfModule(this._id,this._type,
    (data)=>{this._state = data[0].state; resolve(data[0].state);}
   );
  });

  return promise;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Module.getState returns a promise.

The line `setTimeout(()=>console.log(tempMod.getState()),1000);`
is waiting 1000ms, then console logging the result of `tempMod.getState()`, which is an unresolved promise.

If you do not want to be getting `Promise { <pending> }` in the console. You can change it to

```js
setTimeout(() => tempMod.getState().then((result) => {
  console.log(result)
}), 1000);
```

---

As for the looping issue. When you are using `.then()`. The rest of the code after the `.then()` will immediately run. In particular the `i++`. Only the code that is inside the `then` callback will be delayed.

When you changed this to `await`. the entire function will stop executing until the promise resolves. That means the `i++` will not be executed.

I am assuming `ifArray.length` is 1 and i starts at 0. So when you get to `if(i < ifArray.length){` This will be true when using await (as `i++` did not execute) which will cause innerLoop to be called again.
The same thing will keep happening as `i++` will never be executed.